# Plugin method not found

Tags: magento2, after-plugin

This is my plugin:

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin;

use Magento\Email\Controller\Adminhtml\Email\Template\DefaultTemplate;

class MyPlugin
{
    public function afterExecute(DefaultTemplate $template, $result)
    {
        $text = $template->getData('template_text');
        $text .= '<p>Custom Text</p>';
        $template->setData('template_text', $text);
    }
}
```

Var dump works. Plugin executes, but I can't get why getData method is not found. Any suggestions?

Comment: You can use `get_class_methods` to check available methods for your `$template` object.

Answer (score 0):

You have done wrong.The original function `execute()` does have return `@return **void**` .So, for you `$result` is void type **variable** and also how you can `$template` variable as your **return** does not give any parameters like that?. and `$template` give `Magento\Email\Controller\Adminhtml\Email\Template\DefaultTemplate` class object.

If you want `$template` variable data then you have to use

```
$template = $template->getRequest()->getParam('code');
```

Actually, You have to explain what you to achieve?